# Will this remove, and only remove, selection keys which are ready to read data?

Tags: java, sockets, selector, nio

In my program, I want to ensure last messages from my server are sent letting the clients know a shutdown was initiated, so I want to prevent more commands being accepted while allowing the selector loop to continue till all messages are finished sending.

To this end, I want to be able to deregister all keys allowing input from the clients, will this work as intended?

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    for (SelectionKey key : sel.keys()) {
        if (key.interestOps() == SelectionKey.OP_READ) {
            key.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any help, much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm unsure if I need to do bitwise operation on returned selection key before comparison. Behaviour of program is currently showing this could or could not be working, this happens during shutdown so hard to tell if its gracefully shutting down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my program, I want to ensure last messages from my server are sent letting the clients know a shutdown was initiated, so I want to prevent more commands being accepted while allowing the selector loop to continue till all messages are finished sending.
>
> To this end, I want to be able to deregister all keys allowing input from the clients, will this work as intended?

No. It won't send anything on the wire to the clients, and it will prevent you detecting futher read events on the channels, so they will just sit there open indefinitely.

You need to either *close* those channels, which seems the most obvious solution, unless you have pending output or at least *shutdown* the associated socket for input.

But this is a very strange requirement. The clients shouldn't be sending new requests while prior responses are still pending. The application protocol should take care of this, not fiddling around with sockets.

Comment: So is the best solution to gobble input and leave keys untouched until shutdown message is confirmed sent? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am entirely unable to comprehend how you can possibly derive that suggestion from what I said.

Comment: Ah I had a look at socket methods and just saw that shutdownInput() was one(was trying to figure out what you meant), I think that will suit nicely, many thanks.

Comment: The problem arose from the fact that each client has one persistent connection (Its a MUD/Text type game, all communication is on one connection), so there is somewhat constant back and forward on that one socket.

Comment: Well you don't really need to do anything except *deregister* those keys for OP_READ, i.e. clear the OP_READ bit in the `interestOps`; keep writing; and then close the socket. If there is pending unread data when you do that, the client will get a 'connection reset' instead of a clean close, and if he sends enough of it he will either block or else start needing OP_WRITE if you're using NIO at the client (why?).

Comment: Will shutdownInput() still behave ok while selector testing connection for READ operation?

Comment: It will look to you like an EOS: an OP_READ for which the following `read()` returns zero. How it looks to the client depends on the server operating system: a subsequent client send will either (a) cause a connection reset (Windows), (b) cause a block or EWOULDBLOCK (Linux), or be totally ignored (Unix).

Comment: No NIO at client, just a simple socket (its based on simplified telnet IO), so I think closing connection with existing unused input is fine.

Comment: Correction: an OP_READ for which a following read returns -1.